# Dell G5 15 screen brightness changes with different web pages/apps

Tags: laptop

I recently purchased Dell G5 15 and I am having a weird problem though. Any time I open a new screen (either a new web page or any type of screen) brightness changes. Apparently, others have also had similar issues but their solutions didn't work for me. There is no **Power Options > Display > Enable Adaptive Brightness > Set it to Off** in my settings. I also tried to change from **Services.msc** but didn't work. Does anyone have other ideas? I am using Windows 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are referring to the feature Content-Aware Brightness Control in Dell laptops. I too have faced this issue before. I am assuming that you are using one of their newer models, so the BIOS should be updated. If not, you can try updating your BIOS. Under the display settings in the BIOS menu, there should be an option to disable Eco mode. Do so, and reboot. It should work - at least it did for me.

Good luck.

Comment: Wow! Thank you it worked!!!